# Multiple pings from a client to a server

Tags: windows, web, networking, server, ip

I have 2 Virtual Machines. One is a Windows(say client). The other one is a CentOS(say server).

My Windows (Client) IP is 1.1.1.1

My CentOS (Server) has an app running and is listening on port 12345. IP address of the CentOS VM is 2.2.2.2.

I want to generate multiple pings  from the windows VM from specific IP/ports to CentOS VM specific IP/ports.
i.e generate multiple pings from a certain port + source IP of 1.1.1.1 to destination IP of 2.2.2.2 + destination port number 12345.

I am looking for  something like the foll:

**** ping    DIP   D.Port    SIP    S.Port    -count 1000 ****

Please note: I need to run this ping from my windows CMD.

Is there a way I can do this from my windows CMD line?

Comment: Pings are ICMP echos; ICMP is a protocol itself (Protocol Number = 1); ping does NOT "ride on" UDP(Protocol Numbers = 17) or TCP(Protocol Numbers = 6), so there is no port #.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using ping.

Answer (score 0):

check your system docs, on mine it is:

```
Mac_3.2.57$ping -S 10.0.0.148 -c 100000 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) from 10.0.0.148: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=25.521 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=18.837 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=16.605 ms
```